# Let Y be a convex subset of a vector space X. Show that for every x ∈ X, the set Y + x = {y + x : y ∈ Y } is convex.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let Y be a convex subset of a vector space X. Show that for every
x ∈ X, the set Y + x = {y + x : y ∈ Y } is convex.

Comment: what have you tried? (hint: use the definition of convex)

Comment: What stops you form a one-line, intuitive proof?

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively, the set $Y + x$ is just the set $Y$ "shifted" by $x$.

A convex set is one such that the line segment between any two points in the set is also in the set.

What does that tell you about a line $l$ in $Y$ and its corresponding line $l + x$ in $Y + x$?